# Imaging and illumination plane in microscope

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, microscopy

I've been delving into the intricacies of achieving Kohler illumination in microscopy, and the term 'illumination and image-forming rays' consistently surfaces. Most resources emphasize the simultaneous consideration of these rays before delving into the methods for achieving Kohler illumination. So my question is why there are 2 sets of ray?

[image: Kohler illumination]

This is typically something that can be found accompanying such articles. Another equivalent way of asking (I guess) is why the light coming from the light source is divergent in 1 case (illumination path) while collimated in the other (imaging path)?

Answer (score 1):

"Seeing" involves "illuminating" and "collecting".
When you read a book the ambient light illuminates the book (uniformly) and you do not observe the origin of the light and your eye focuses the light originating from each point on the book and produces a sharp image on the retina.
Köhler illumination is designed to produce even illumination of the specimen using a diverging/parallel beam of light without the real image of the source of light being "visible", note in your diagram the plane containing the real image of the light source is a long way away from the plane of the specimen.
The light from the specimen is focused by the lens system to produce an image of the specimen.

---

[image]

So notice that with the condenser lens more of the light from light source, $BB'$ reach the specimen and then those rays which pass through the specimen provide, after passing through the objective lens and tube lens which form the image of the specimen on the camera sensor, uniform illumination as a background over the camera sensor.

Comment: This really is another way of saying that are always 2 paths although my question is really why there are 2. Let's look at the light source, why is it divergent/parallel like in your answer? What does that mean? Are you saying if I have a point source it can be both divergent and collimated? Or is this some special treatment for extended source? Shouldn't extended source be just considered as multiple point sources? Also, what does it mean when you say "diverging/parallel beam of light"? If I have a single lens, I will have 2 focal points? 1 for divergent, 1 for parallel??

Comment: I see that are some edits but I still fail to see how this address the question. You are saying more light reaches the sample via the condenser lens which ends up as a background in the sensor. So what about the imaging part that the field stop is imaged on the sensor? In that path the light immediately after the aperture stop is collimated. So what is it? collimated or divergent? Yeah I know its both. The question is why is it both. Imaging in geometric optics always treat object as point sources. If it is placed at infinity it is collimated but never both.

Comment: *Another equivalent way of asking (I guess) is why the light coming from the light source is divergent in 1 case (illumination path) while collimated in the other (imaging path)?* What the diagrams show are *construction* rays. To form the image on the camera sensor there are many more rays which start at points on the specimen and produce corresponding images on the camera sensor.

Comment: I have found an interactive tutorial which might be of interest to you? [Microscope Alignment for Köhler Illumination](https://www.microscopyu.com/tutorials/kohler} and also the Wikipedia article [Köhler illumination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6hler_illumination) as that explains why Köhler illumination was better than previous ways of illuminating a specimen.

Comment: Are you suggesting that there are collimated and divergent rays coming out of a light source?

Answer (score 0):

I will give a different answer than Farcher, although his is fine.

You see, lenses are transforming objects and they have no regard for the source of light, its previous path. All they do is Fourier transform what is in one focal plane, to the next focal plane.

What is meant in the diagrams is the following: the sample is at the focal plane of the microscope objective-> that is what you want to image! So, after the microscope objective, you have a collimated beam of light which encodes the image of your sample. After that, you use a second lens to form a real image of the sample onto your sensor by placing a sensor at the focal plane of a this second lens.

Now, if you were to use an illumination that was forming a real image onto the sample (ie, "focusing"), you would re-image that image on your sensor, which would super-impose with what you want to image, and that you do not want.

So, you devise an illumination, prior of your sample, which guarantees a uniform illumination, but no image of the light source. The light can be collimated or divergent, or convergent, it does not matter much as long as if satisfies your criteria of being not an image of your light source and is uniform enough.

Another way of seeing this is that you illuminate your sample with say collimated light, but now the features in your sample are new point source emitters, and those have a divergent nature to it. So it is instructive to look at an imaging path (sample has point source emitters) and an illumination path (you made sure there is no real image there, so its not a "focus" of your light source).

EDIT:

Exercise to OP. Consider the following arrangement of optics. The black straight lines are lenses. All elements up to lens #2 are a focal distance apart, last lens is 2f from lens #2. Imagine that the LEDs are like pixels from your phone: extremely tiny (or not, or just a regular LED, sincerely, it does not matter, but maybe for your own internal visualization, it is easier that way).
[image]

In which planes will you see an image of LED1 and which planes will you see an image of LED2?

After you answer that question, try to draw parallels, with your own question:

Does a light source/image need to be active (e.g. an LED)? Or can it be passive and have other features, like shadows, color filtering, etc?

Is it wrong to interpret a lens as transforming all light input, regardless of its source? Would it not be more instructive to break down this light input into pieces which are easier to visualize and understand, instead of treating ALL possible inputs? (another example of an input on lens #2 that is not depicted in my drawing is, e.g. a plane half way between lens #1 and LED 2: what happens to that plane in my drawing? Does it matter, or should I discard it in my context? To better visualize that plane, include a third LED, green, half way between lens 1 and LED2. To understand that that plane is also relevant to the whole system try to imagine that you have that arrangement of optics and some dust flies through on that plane: it definitely affected the light, but how?)

Comment: This is another thing I heard almost everywhere but don't understand why "lens does Fourier transform". Where does that come from? Fourier optics? In Fourier optics the first thing textbooks say is plane wave i.e. coherent light source and if you really think about it, it has to be coherent light else you can't sum the light to approximate the Fourier expression. That being the case, why is this relevant? The light source here need not be coherent and most of the time it isn't.

Comment: Coming back to your comment, I don't see how you are answering the question. Basically you are saying Kohler is not critical illumination. "The light can be collimated or divergent, or convergent" This is my problem. The illumination and imaging path exist SIMULTANEOUSLY. Its not that they are separate extreme cases catering to light source of different divergence. "... the features in your sample are new point source emitters" agree on this but that is not my question. I am ok with this. My question is really why the light source is drawn as divergent in 1 case and collimated in the other

Comment: You say you are fine with the sample being point emitters, yet you disregard why point emitters are treated as a divergent source. And no, the light source per se is not treated as collimated in one case and collimated in the other: the light source IS collimated. The "imprinted" shadows or features of your sample are new features, to which your microscope does not give a damn whether you have a light source behind or not. You want to image your sample? Good: image the sample, use the right setup from sample to display. You want to illuminate your sample? Good, use the left image.

Comment: I think really that the biggest problem you face is shedding previous notions of what light is, because you are confusing light with imaging in this question. The path on the  right is a way to visualize two real (imaging) planes that pertain to the sample, while the image on the left is used to visualize the real (imaging) planes of the light source and to show that these do not coincide! In this case the real planes of your sample are the planes containing the conjugates of the light source. And no, lenses do make fourier transforms, no need for coherence

Comment: @CoffeeBiscuit see my updated answer. I think that if I had inverted the whole picture of your question and had the illumination be not transmittive but reflective(ie, using a beamsplitter to couple it from the microscope side), you would immediately accept both cases: the illumination illuminating your sample from below with collimated light, and your sample being treated as just an object you want to image, ie, divergent light coming from the sample. However they are exactly the same case, except one is transmittive, the other reflective.

Comment: Ok let's start with your drawing. I don't really know what you are trying to achieve with this. Clearly LED1 forms image at plane 1 while LED2 at plane 2. So what is this suppose to explain? Divergence affects focal? Yes I know that and in fact that is my question from the start. Plane 1 is like the field stop of the system so at plane 2 is the light focused or collimated? Answer depends on the input but I only have 1 source. You see the question?

Comment: Since when did I disregard point source as divergent? I just can't accept why they are treated as divergent and collimated AT THE SAME TIME. I don't really know what you are getting at for the rest of the statement. It seems you are saying the left and right setup don't happen at the same time. If that is the case, you will be wrong. In all the articles I read they occur simultaneously hence my confusion.  "And no, lenses do make fourier transforms, no need for coherence" my question is why doesn't it need coherence but your response is "yeah it doesn't" ...

Comment: Look, I am trying to help you with your confusion. It's not me who has problems interpreting those schematics or Farcher's answer, and it's your own confusion that is drawing wrong assumptions about what I wrote. I am only devoting so much time in trying to get you in the right path because I had surgery and I am currently in sick leave. Otherwise I would had been long gone as trying to come up with innovative ways on how to get you on the right path is very time consuming. So, I will try one last time

Comment: In my first comment I realize now I made a mistake: it should read "...the light source per se is not treated as collimated in one case and not collimated in the other: the light source IS collimated." So this immediately disproves your interpretation of "It seems you are saying the left and right setup don't happen at the same time.". Because they do, and that is what my image was trying to achieve. In plane 2, light from LED1 is collimated and light from LED2 is imaged (focused). (comment #1, continues)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149576/discussion-between-jose-andrade-and-coffeebiscuit).